# PowerShell - Why does Get-ChildItem does not return any output

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the filenames that are created within a datetime range.

```
[datetime]$start = '2020-06-01 10:00:00'
[datetime]$end = '2020-06-01 11:00:00'
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -Name | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $start -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $end }
```

Why does this piece of code doesnt return me anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `-Name` parameter returns only the name of the file as a String type instead of an object. Therefore it has no `LastWriteTime` attribute to search against.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7

```bsh
PS C:\> (gci)[0].GetType() 

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DirectoryInfo                            System.IO.FileSystemInfo


PS C:\> (gci -Name)[0].GetType()  

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

```bsh
PS C:\> gci 


    Directory: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2/11/2019  12:08 AM                %homeshare%
d-----        5/12/2019   2:54 PM                Code
d-----       21/03/2019   5:11 PM                Intel
d-----       28/10/2019   9:54 AM                Microsoft
d-----       13/12/2019   5:15 PM                NVIDIA
d-r---       28/05/2020   7:27 PM                Program Files
d-r---        4/05/2020  11:00 AM                Program Files (x86)
d-r---       17/02/2020   1:43 PM                Users
d-----       31/05/2020  10:50 PM                Windows
```

VS `-Name`

```bsh
PS C:\> gci -Name 
%homeshare%
Code
Intel
Microsoft
NVIDIA
Program Files       
Program Files (x86) 
Users
Windows
```

You can filter the object, then select the names if that is required:

```bsh
PS C:\> gci | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 1 -Day 10) } | Select-Object Name

Name
----
Program Files
Program Files (x86)
Users
Windows
SUService.log
```

If you need the file path instead of the file name, you can use `FullName`:

```bsh
FullName
--------
C:\Program Files
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

Comment: +1.  It'd probably be helpful to include how to get the desired output with `Get-ChildItem ... | Where-Object { ... } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'`.

Comment: Tried `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $start -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $end } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name' ` but it still doesn't return anything

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but still how can i get the filenames as a string output?

Comment: @CheangWaiBin I've updated the post. You can pipe to filtered output and grab the string at the end.   Thanks BACON, good point.